# Hive: count matches between INNER JOIN on unique values of a column

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to count matches between columns resulting from an INNER JOIN of two tables on unique values of a single column in one of the two tables. An example may make things more clear:

If I had the following two tables:

```
Table A
-------
id_A:   info_A
1       'a'
2       'b'
3       'c'
3       'd'

Table B
-------
id_B:   info_B
1       'a'
3       'c'
5       'b'
```

I want to find the unique `id_A`: `[1,2,3]` and the `info_A` associated with them: `['a','b','c','d']`.

I want to create a table that looks like the following:

```
Table join of A+B
-----------------
id_A:   info_A   id_B   info_B    match_cnt
1       'a'      1      'a'       1
3       'c','d'  3      'c'       0.5
```

where `match_cnt` is the number of matches between `info_A` and `info_B` for a given `id_A`. FYI, the actual tables I'm working with have billions of rows.

A code chunk demonstrates what I've tried, plus variations (not shown below):

```
SELECT z.id_A, z.info_A, z.id_B, z.info_B
FROM(
    SELECT u.id_A AS id_A, u.info_A AS info_A, y.id_B AS true_id_B, y.info_B AS true_info_B
    FROM db.table_A u
    WHERE EXISTS 
       ( SELECT id_B, info_B
         FROM table_B l
         where l.id_B= u.id_A)
    INNER JOIN table_B y
    ON u.id_A = y.id_B
    ) z
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select      id
           ,collect_list (case when a=1 then info end)                  as info_a
           ,collect_list (case when b=1 then info end)                  as info_b
           ,count        (case when a=1 and b=1 then 1 end) / count(*)  as match_cnt

from       (select      id
                       ,info
                       ,min (case when tab = 'A' then 1 end)    as a
                       ,min (case when tab = 'B' then 1 end)    as b

            from        (           select 'A' as tab ,id_A as id ,info_A as info from A
                        union all   select 'B' as tab ,id_B as id ,info_B as info from B
                        ) t

            group by    id
                       ,info
            ) t

group by    id

having      min(a) = 1
        and min(b) = 1
;
```

---

```
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
| id |  info_a   | info_b | match_cnt |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | ["a"]     | ["a"]  | 1.0       |
|  3 | ["c","d"] | ["c"]  | 0.5       |
+----+-----------+--------+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use some thing  like below :-

```
 WITH T1 AS ( select ID_A ,count(1) as cnt from tableA inner join tableB on tableA.ID_A=tableB.ID_B and tableA.INFO_A=tableB.INFO_B  group by ID_A,INFO_A)

      select distinct tmp.ID_A,tmp.a,tmp.ID_B,tmp.b, (cnt/size(a)) from 

      (select ID_A ,collect_set(INFO_A) as a,ID_B,collect_set(INFO_B) as b from tableA inner join tableB on tableA.a=tableB.a group by tableA.a,tableB.a)

 tmp join T1 on T1.ID_A=tmp.ID_A
```